# ROS Answers SE migration: Libogre Error

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I am facing a problem with Gazebo. When I install it on my machine running Ubuntu Linux 12.04, it works fine but when I restart the computer and try to run it, it gives me the following error.

gazebo: error while loading shared libraries: libOgreRTShaderSystem.so.1.7.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Has any body else faced the same problem? What might be the possible solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/275/libogre-error/) by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 39 on 2012-11-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Make sure you sourced the `setup.sh` file that is installed in `/usr/share/gazebo-<version>`.

I place the following line in my `~/.bashrc` file so that `setup.sh` is sourced at the appropriate time:

> source /usr/share/gazebo-1.2/setup.sh

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mfahad](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/95/mfahad/) on 2012-11-28**:
Thanks, that fixed it.

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-11-29**:
@mfahad, please mark Nate's answer as being correct if possible so that others can easily see the problem is solved.